# Three plot in one figure using Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want my plot to look like the image below, how can I achieve that using Matplotlib?

[image]

And thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GridSpec` similar to [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html). Possibly there will be not enough space for the y tick labels, which can be mitigated by increasing the default `wspace`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2, figsize=(12, 7), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.4})
gs = axs[0, 0].get_gridspec()
for ax in axs.ravel():
    ax.remove()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :2])
ax1.set_ylabel('A')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2:])
ax2.set_ylabel('B')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1:3])
ax3.set_ylabel('C')
for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3):
    ax.set_xlabel('D')
    ax.legend(handles=[], title='legend', loc='upper right', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]